# Use decimal values in spinner javaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Im building a small application where i need to take some inputs with decimal values(Double values). I added some **SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory** to define the the min.max,default double values, but when i click the spinner's increment button it wont increase with the decimal values, it increments as integer.

```
@FXML
    private Spinner<Double> fixedAciditySpinner;

 @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    this.fixedAciditySpinner.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory(0.00, 100.00, 0.00));
}
```

How can i get the spinner working with decimal values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do through FXML is to set the value factory the min max and the amountToStepBy

```
<Spinner fx:id="spinner" editable="true" >
            <valueFactory>
                <SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory min="0.0" max="10.0" initialValue="5.0" amountToStepBy="0.1"/>
            </valueFactory>
        </Spinner>
```

Of course you need to include the DoubleSpinnerValueFactory into the FXML file

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory.DoubleSpinnerValueFactory?>
```

The above will make your Spinner work with doubles but when you have a value like "5" as you will see it's presentation will be as an int and not like 5.0.

Comment: Im using a spinner not slider

Answer (score 1):

```
<Spinner fx:id="sp" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4" editable="true" 
min="3.2" max="5.0" initialValue="3.2" amountToStepBy=".1"/>
```

Do this it is much easier